# Plotting one row of an image

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to plot only one row of an image with matplotlib in Python3?

I load an image using opencv and want to plot only one row of it.

For now I have only this code to read and show the whole image.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("test.png", 3)

cv2.imshow("Original", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, can you please add a minimal running version of your code?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(r"content.jpg", 3)

print(image.shape)


cv2.imshow("Original", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

row = 100
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
mask[row,:,:] = 1
image[mask == 0] = 0

cv2.imshow("Masked", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original Image:

[image]

Masked Image:

[image]

---

Note that reading images with openCV yields numpy arrays, on which you may perform numpy operations such as slicing and masking.